# Is there a hard limit as to how many columns can be returned in C# SqlDataAdapter Fill?

Tags: c#, dataset, sqldataadapter

I'm currently working on a legacy project that has some SQL needs to run to get some data. 
They use DataTables, DataSets, etc to work with the data.

The query in question that gets executed only returns one row, however it contains well over 700 columns.

Unfortunately when the code executes to fill the data set, if the query contains over 655 columns, nothing gets returned.

Is there a way to get around this limitation so if a query returns 656+ columns data will get returned or is there some other workaround?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Chasing a red herring. The data is there, I just can't view it in the debugger as a table if there's 656+ columns in the data. The viewer can't handle more than 655.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is there, I just can't view it in the debugger as a table if there's 656+ columns in the data. The viewer can't handle more than 655.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it resolve the issue but try using the overloaded `Fill` method

`DbDataAdapter.Fill(Int32, Int32, DataTable[])`.

As per MSDN document:

> Adds or refreshes rows in a DataTable to match those in the data
>   source starting at the specified record and retrieving up to the
>   **specified maximum number of records**

See here for more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5wy74x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This only appears to deal with records. There is only 1 record to deal with here. The issue has to do with the number of columns in the data set. So for instance if "select * from myTable" where * contains 655 or fewer columns the adapter fills and I get data back. Anything over 655 and nothing is returned. Although in actuality if I went directly to a column in the debugger and tried to see the data it'd be there which makes it that much more frustrating.

Comment: @univegar304, honestly I never ran into such issue where a table has 700 columns (I would rather break that table to multiple linked table), neither I am aware of any such limitation on number of columns `fill` method can populate. What I proposed is an alternative. BTW, where you are populating that data (I mean in grid/list ...).

Comment: unfortunately this is a legacy app so I'm stuck with what I have for the moment. I'm not actually displaying the data directly. It merely gathers a record that it uses to then uses to build a page. Also the code in question is a major part of the framework for the app so this could be affecting other things unintentionally. I just think the original architects were unaware of this apparent limitation when they designed this thing. So my only options are to find a workaround or give them the bad news that it's unfix-able.

Comment: @univegar304, just use the alternative method in my answer and see if it works. At least you have a workaround then at hand.

Comment: I get the same results. No data getting populated in the table. Anything over 655 columns in my query and I get nothing.

Comment: Apparently this is a red herring. I do get my data, I just can't display it in the debugger. Must me a limitation in the viewer. I found the root problem in my code base. Thanks for your suggestion/comments.

Comment: You'r welcome. Great to hear that you got it worked.